# Complex exponential function identity proof

Tags: exponential-function

I see the following identity in my book however they don't prove it so I am wondering how to prove that $e^{i \theta_1+i\theta_2}=e^{i\theta_1}e^{i\theta_2}$?

The definition is:

$$e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$$

Comment: If you are able to use $e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$ then double angle formulae will do the trick.

Comment: I guess that this depends on what your definition is of $e^z$ for a complex number $z$.

Comment: @fGDu94 yes that is the correct defintion.

Comment: @Lubin I have included the definition.

Comment: More precisely, @fGDu94 , it’s the addition formula, not the double-angle formula.

Comment: double angle formulae is my catch all term for it, but yes, addition formulae is a good name for it

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**
$$e^{i\theta_1}e^{i\theta_2}=\bigl(\cos(\theta_1)+i\sin(\theta_1) \bigr) \bigl(\cos(\theta_2)+i\sin(\theta_2)\bigr)$$

Just open the brackets.

Comment: @Robben You can also define the exponential function by its power series and then prove exp(z)exp(z')=exp(z+z') for any complex numbers z and z'. Let me know if you would like the details.